# Using Mailx with Gmail

Tags: mailx, gmail

I've installed mailx, and when I try to send an email, like:

```
echo "Test" | mailx -r "foo@gmail.com" -s "Test" "bar@gmail.com"
```

It executes. But I don't receive the email. How do I set mailx up to send to Gmail, while retaining the ability to customize the sender ID?

Comment: Did you check your Spam in the Gmail account? I can send mails from command line and also use the `-r` option. But those mails end up in the spam folder.

Comment: Yes, I checked Spam. How did you do this? Are you able to change the sender's name as well?

Comment: Yes I could change the senders address. I have a postfix running, which sends the mail. Not sure how your setup is in detail, but you also might want to check the logfile of your MTA.

Comment: I'll try setting up postfix again. What are the steps I need to follow, and the specific configuration options I need to set?

Comment: Configfiles for postfix looks pretty default for me.

Comment: Hmmm. Would you mind sending the contents of your /etc/postfix/main.cf? Just to make sure I have everything down.

Comment: Just to be clear, you can set both the sender as well as the reciever as Gmail IDs? @Thomas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60632/discussion-between-thomas-and-pk123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without some form of authentication that you are the correct user.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing

This used to be a big problem, before people fixed it with cryptographic signatures. You could receive an email from a criminal, pretending to be your boss, asking you to send them the `secret project of the future`.

If you host your own mail server, you will be able to customise the username, but you will either need to have some way of keeping your IP constant (or replies will not work), or DDNS.

EDIT:

as @tripleee mentioned, this has to be set up as SMTP settings, this is not a mailx problem

Comment: Maybe point out that the authentication needs to be configured on the SMTP level, and isn't a Mailx problem directly at all.

Comment: Ah right that makes sense. Can I change the sender name as long as it isn't a Gmail ID then? Like an ID from a private server?

Comment: If you have a mail server, or one that will give you the address you want, then you can use that name. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_authentication